# Qt cannot find the standard header

Tags: qt, compilation

The compilation is failing due to standard Qt include files/ library missing, why?

I have custom toolchain for devices. My compilation fails with messages:

**In file included from /opt/STM/STLinux-2.3/devkit/sh4/target/usr/include/QtCore/QString:1:0,
                 from ./menuitems/Item.h:5,
                 from ./appmessages/AppMessageAgeLimit.h:4,
                 from appmessages/AMessageDispatcher.cpp:2:
/opt/STM/STLinux-2.3/devkit/sh4/target/usr/include/QtCore/qstring.h:60:22: fatal error: string: No such file or directory**

It guess that this toolchain has been configured wrong but I don't know how to fix it. Below is output from "/opt/STM/STLinux-2.3/devkit/sh4/bin/sh4-linux-g++ -v" command - may be it will be useful:

*Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=/opt/STM/STLinux-2.3/devkit/sh4/bin/sh4-linux-g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/opt/STM/STLinux-2.3/devkit/sh4/libexec/gcc/sh4-linux/4.8.2/lto-wrapper
Target: sh4-linux
Configured with: /home/viatcheslavvgavrilov/qt/gcc-4.8.2/configure --target=sh4-linux --prefix=/opt/STM/STLinux-2.3/devkit/sh4 --exec-prefix=/opt/STM/STLinux-2.3/devkit/sh4 --bindir=/opt/STM/STLinux-2.3/devkit/sh4/bin --sbindir=/opt/STM/STLinux-2.3/devkit/sh4/sbin --sysconfdir=/opt/STM/STLinux-2.3/devkit/sh4/etc --datadir=/opt/STM/STLinux-2.3/devkit/sh4/share --includedir=/opt/STM/STLinux-2.3/devkit/sh4/include --libdir=/opt/STM/STLinux-2.3/devkit/sh4/lib --libexecdir=/opt/STM/STLinux-2.3/devkit/sh4/libexec --localstatedir=/opt/STM/STLinux-2.3/devkit/sh4/var --sharedstatedir=/opt/STM/STLinux-2.3/devkit/sh4/share --mandir=/opt/STM/STLinux-2.3/devkit/sh4/man --infodir=/opt/STM/STLinux-2.3/devkit/sh4/info --enable-checking=assert --program-prefix=sh4-linux- --with-local-prefix=/opt/STM/STLinux-2.3/devkit/sh4 --with-sysroot=/opt/STM/STLinux-2.3/devkit/sh4/target --enable-languages=c,c++ --enable-threads=posix --enable-nls --enable-c99 --enable-long-long --with-system-zlib --enable-shared --disable-libgomp --enable-multilib --with-multilib-list=m4,m4-nofpu --enable-symvers=gnu --with-gxx-include-dir=/target/usr/include/c++/4.2.4 --enable-__cxa_atexit
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.8.2 20131016 (GCC)*

Comment: You supposed to ask the question, right? I can only assume that you want that to be solved but more complex posts to here should involve the statement with question mark, I guess. And I believe just any question should be specific question statement here.

Answer (score 0):

> The compilation is failing due to standard Qt include files/ library missing, why?

Checking on [qt.conf](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt-conf.html) file section Paths prefix usually helps:

```
[Paths]
Prefix=/some/path
```

With my several statically built Qt flavors it is usually set to one of:

```
[Paths]
Prefix=/specific_prebuilt_qt/src/qtbase
```

And the default prefix may point to one directory up which can be the valid case but then make sure the path to Qt tool-chain is correct. Or where's `bin` folder for the Qt you intend to use? The folder where qmake tool is.

```
[Paths]
Prefix=..
```

Make sure after the prefix path fixed qmake executed for your project before building again.

Comment: Yes that is what I wanted ask. Unfortunately I haven't qt.conf. The installation of my toolchain was simple copying to opt directory. I guess it is root case of my problem. I haven't any other way to install it. May be I should edit qmake.conf file to resolve my issue.

Comment: Mind the file name: qt.conf and it is located in Qt bin directory.

Comment: @RomanKazmin You need to build Qt with installation directory set to the same one as the one on the target. Once it's built you can then copy it over to the target and it'll work correctly.

Comment: @Kuda Ober, I do that same trick with the soft link but minding the Prefix.